# Cascade primary key update to all referencing foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key, update, referential-integrity

Is it possible to update a primary key column value with cascading the update among all the foreign keys referencing it ?

**# EDIT 1:** 
When I run followinq query

```
select * from sys.foreign_keys where referenced_object_id=OBJECT_ID('myTable')
```

, I see that update_referential_action is set to 0. Thus NO ACTION is taken after updating my primary keys columns. How can I update the foreign keys to make them **ON CASCADE UPDATE** ?

**# EDIT 2 :**
In order to script out creation or dropping of all foreign keys in your schema run the following script (taken from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2958.script-to-create-all-foreign-keys.aspx))

```
DECLARE @schema_name sysname;

DECLARE @table_name sysname;

DECLARE @constraint_name sysname;

DECLARE @constraint_object_id int;

DECLARE @referenced_object_name sysname;

DECLARE @is_disabled bit;

DECLARE @is_not_for_replication bit;

DECLARE @is_not_trusted bit;

DECLARE @delete_referential_action tinyint;

DECLARE @update_referential_action tinyint;

DECLARE @tsql nvarchar(4000);

DECLARE @tsql2 nvarchar(4000);

DECLARE @fkCol sysname;

DECLARE @pkCol sysname;

DECLARE @col1 bit;

DECLARE @action char(6);  

DECLARE @referenced_schema_name sysname;



DECLARE FKcursor CURSOR FOR

     select OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)

         , OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), name, OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)

         , object_id

         , is_disabled, is_not_for_replication, is_not_trusted

         , delete_referential_action, update_referential_action, OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id)

    from sys.foreign_keys

    order by 1,2;

OPEN FKcursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @constraint_name

    , @referenced_object_name, @constraint_object_id

    , @is_disabled, @is_not_for_replication, @is_not_trusted

    , @delete_referential_action, @update_referential_action, @referenced_schema_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN



      IF @action <> 'CREATE'

        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE '

                  + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)

                  + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name) + ';';

    ELSE

        BEGIN

        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE '

                  + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)

                  + CASE @is_not_trusted

                        WHEN 0 THEN ' WITH CHECK '

                        ELSE ' WITH NOCHECK '

                    END

                  + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name)

                  + ' FOREIGN KEY (';

        SET @tsql2 = '';

        DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR FOR

            select COL_NAME(fk.parent_object_id, fkc.parent_column_id)

                 , COL_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id, fkc.referenced_column_id)

            from sys.foreign_keys fk

            inner join sys.foreign_key_columns fkc

            on fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id

            where fkc.constraint_object_id = @constraint_object_id

            order by fkc.constraint_column_id;

        OPEN ColumnCursor;

        SET @col1 = 1;

        FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @fkCol, @pkCol;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

        BEGIN

            IF (@col1 = 1)

                SET @col1 = 0;

            ELSE

            BEGIN

                SET @tsql = @tsql + ',';

                SET @tsql2 = @tsql2 + ',';

            END;

            SET @tsql = @tsql + QUOTENAME(@fkCol);

            SET @tsql2 = @tsql2 + QUOTENAME(@pkCol);

            FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @fkCol, @pkCol;

        END;

        CLOSE ColumnCursor;

        DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor;

       SET @tsql = @tsql + ' ) REFERENCES ' + QUOTENAME(@referenced_schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@referenced_object_name)

                  + ' (' + @tsql2 + ')';

        SET @tsql = @tsql

                  + ' ON UPDATE ' + CASE @update_referential_action

                                        WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION '

                                        WHEN 1 THEN 'CASCADE '

                                        WHEN 2 THEN 'SET NULL '

                                        ELSE 'SET DEFAULT '

                                    END

                  + ' ON DELETE ' + CASE @delete_referential_action

                                        WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION '

                                        WHEN 1 THEN 'CASCADE '

                                        WHEN 2 THEN 'SET NULL '

                                        ELSE 'SET DEFAULT '

                                    END

                  + CASE @is_not_for_replication

                        WHEN 1 THEN ' NOT FOR REPLICATION '

                        ELSE ''

                    END

                  + ';';

        END;

    PRINT @tsql;

    IF @action = 'CREATE'

        BEGIN

        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE '

                  + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)

                  + CASE @is_disabled

                        WHEN 0 THEN ' CHECK '

                        ELSE ' NOCHECK '

                    END

                  + 'CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name)

                  + ';';

        PRINT @tsql;

        END;

    FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @constraint_name

        , @referenced_object_name, @constraint_object_id

        , @is_disabled, @is_not_for_replication, @is_not_trusted

        , @delete_referential_action, @update_referential_action, @referenced_schema_name;

END;

CLOSE FKcursor;

DEALLOCATE FKcursor;
```

To generate the DROP foreign keys script, modify @action value to be equal to 'DROP' in the declaration clause :

```
DECLARE @action char(6) = 'DROP';
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have defined the Foreign Key constraints as `ON UPDATE CASCADE` then the Primary Key value that was changed should cascade down to all the Foreign Keys with that constraint.

If you do not have the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` constraint, then you will need create scripts to complete the update.

EDIT: Since you do not have the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` constraint, but you want to have that set up, it is a bit of work. SQL Server does not support altering the constraints to a new setting.

It is necessary to iterate through each table that has a FK constraint to the PK table. For each table with the FK:

1. ALTER TABLE to drop the existing FK constraint.
2. ALTER TABLE again to create the ON UPDATE CASCADE constraint for the FK in question.

This takes a bit of effort, but would result in your constraint being properly set for your case.

EDIT 2: The information that you need is found in sys.foreign_keys.  You can select from that table to get all the information you need.

A post from John Paul Cook can be found here:

(http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2958.script-to-create-all-foreign-keys.aspx)

This code will drop and create ALL FK constraints in a database.  You should be able to work from that to make only the changes that you want in your database.

Answer (score 5):

You sure can. `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is what you are looking for.

Here's a small how-to:
http://sqlandme.com/2011/08/08/sql-server-how-to-cascade-updates-and-deletes-to-related-tables/

Basically, when you modify the PK, the cascade will go out and update all the FKs that reference it.  This can be done in your `CREATE` statement, same as if you were doing a `CASCADE DELETE`

Keep an eye on things when you do this because, as I understand it, CASCADE actually runs at the isolation level `SERIALIZABLE` (normally, SQL runs at `READ COMMITTED` by default) behind the scenes so watch for any blocking issues.

Additional info on isolation levels can be found in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Define all the foreign keys as CASCADE UPDATE

If you have not done this, then you'll have to

1. Create a new row with new primary key
2. Update all child tables
3. Remove old row

.. in a transaction of course and watching out for other constraints that could fail